# Help refactoring named_scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, named-scope

I have the following named_scope:

```
  named_scope :commentors, lambda { |*args|
      { :select => 'users.*, count(*) as total_comments',
        :joins => :comments,
        :conditions => { :comments => { :public_comment => 1, :aasm_state => 'posted', :chalkboard_user_id => nil} },
        :group => 'users.id',
        :having => ['count(*) > ?', args.first || 0],
        :order => 'count(*) desc' }
      }
```

I need to refactor the condition to the following:

```
["(public_comment = ? and box IS NOT NULL and can IS NOT NULL and aasm_state != ?", true, 'removed')]
```

I'm not having much luck with the syntax to change the condition.  Can someone be of kind assistance?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: No specific error.  Just ensure how to go about...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you just need to give the table name to the fields.  I am not sure which table `box` and `can` belong to but this should give you an idea:

```
["comments.public_comment = ? and box IS NOT NULL and can IS NOT NULL and comments.aasm_state != ?", true, 'removed')]
```

You also had an open parenthesis at the beginning which I removed.